# Python - Creating a function to check if a number is divisble by other numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that tests to see if a number is divisible by other numbers(submitted in `*args` part below).

When I run `is_divisible(13, 2, 4)` my function returns `False` and when I run `is_divisible(12, 2, 4)` returns True. However `is_divisible(6, 8, 10, 2)` returns `True`. I have no idea what's wrong any help would be much appreciated.

```
def is_divisible(numerator, *args):
    divisors = list(args)
    for number in range(len(divisors)): 
        x = divisors.pop()
        if numerator % x != 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: You `return True` too early - try stepping through the actual process in your head, on paper or using e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 2):

More pythonic solution using `any`:

```
>>> def is_divisible(numerator, *args):
    return not any(numerator % divisor for divisor in args)

>>> is_divisible(13,4,2)
False
>>> is_divisible(60,3,2)
True
```

Comment: (+1) Yes, that's pythonic. However, I'd use `all` instead of `not any`: `all(numerator % divisor == 0 for divisor in args);` That makes things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_divisible(numerator, *args):
    divisors = list(args)
    for divisor in divisors: 
        if numerator % divisor != 0:
            return False
    return True

print(is_divisible(6, 8, 10, 2))
```

Here is your code slightly modified. I presume you wanted to check if your number is divisible by all numbers in the list, that is the reason why I moved `return True` out of the for block. Otherwise you would return the result on the first number from the `*args`, therefore you got mistakenly `True` since 6 was divisible by 2 (but not by 8 or 10).

Comment: *"The reason why you were getting the wrong result is that pop() (without an argument) always pops the last element from the list."* - no, that's not true. *"I presume you wanted to check if your number is divisible by all numbers in the list, that is the reason why I moved return true out of the for block."* - and that's why they were getting the wrong result. Checking them in the reverse order makes **absolutely no difference**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks a lot for clarification, I fixed it.